# Understanding dual basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I've just started to study differential geometry and I'm a bit confused about dual basis vectors. 
If we have a vector space $\textbf{V}$ and a basis $\{\textbf{e}_i\}$, I can define a dual basis $\{\omega^i\}$ in $\textbf{V}^*$ such that: $$ \omega^i(\textbf{e}_j) = \delta^i_j $$ but in some books I found this relationship: $$\omega^i\cdot\textbf{e}_j = \delta^i_j$$ So I don't understand why these two relationships are equals.
 In fact I know that there's an isomophism $\Phi: \textbf{V}\rightarrow\textbf{V}^*$ induced by the inner product in such a way that: $$\tilde v(\textbf{u}) = \textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{u}\qquad\forall\textbf{u}\in\textbf{V}$$ where $\tilde v$ is the covector associated to the vector $\textbf{v}$ by the isomorphism $\Phi$.
 So I expect that the basis associated to the dual basis is exactly the reciprocal basis: $$\omega^i(\textbf{e}_j) = \textbf{e}^i\cdot\textbf{e}_j =\delta^i_j$$ So the dual basis $\{\omega^i\}$ seems to be equal to the reciprocal basis $\{\textbf{e}^i\}$. 
 I think I'm doing a very bad mistake.
 Can anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: It seems like the books you are looking at might just be using different notation and vocabulary for the same thing.  Also, this isn't quite algebraic geometry, even though you are using algebra to study geometry ;)

Comment: i thought the same, but they use the relation $\omega^i\cdot\textbf{e}_j = \delta^i_j$ to calculate, for example, the covariant derivative of a covector ;so the notation is the same. My answer is how to explain this relation. Sorry for the bad tag!

Comment: You are correct in the relation between a basis and a dual basis for inner product spaces see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis#Existence_and_uniqueness. The isomorphism you mention shows that the differing notations are different ways of viewing the same thing.

Comment: i've understood my mistake for these notations, the key is to see the scalar product between a vector and a covector as a tensor of rank (1,1), that's the application of a covector to a vector or vice versa; while the scalar product between two vectors as a tensor of rank (0,2), that's the metric tensor; and finally the scalar product between two covectors as a tensor of rank (2,0), that's the inverse metric tensor. So, the two relations use the same notation but with different meaning.